# C#: ILogger as logging tool

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, logging, asp.net-core, .net-core

I want to know the advantages to use **ILogger** as logging tool for .net framework and .net core under `Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;`

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Compared to? Hand-crafted logging? Or a specific logging framework like Serilog?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Microsoft.Extensions.Logging` merely provides a logging facade. There's other libraries that do the same thing, such as `Common.Logging`, and to a certain extent Serilog.

The facade pattern is a way of abstracting away an particular implementation of functionality. Here, all your code really cares about it logging. Whether those logs go to the console, a database, Application Insights, etc. is totally inconsequential.

That is what `Ilogger` provides you. It's a consistent interface for generically logging. You can then decide to use whatever actual logging provider you want later or switch between them at a whim, without effecting any of your application code.